# Run on-worker setup programs in SLURM sbatch script

Tags: slurm, sbatch

How do I run setup code in a SLURM sbatch script? Can I just use two `srun` lines?

Are these two `srun` lines guaranteed to run on the same node, without cleanup inbetween?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Parameters
#SBATCH ...

# setup
srun cp /nfs/data $TMPDIR

# job
srun a.out $TMPDIR
```

Answer (score 0):

The `srun` command will start as many instances of the command as specified with the `--ntasks` parameter. It is typically used with MPI programs and programs that run embarrassingly parallel workloads.

A command like `srun cp ...` only makes sense in the case multiple nodes are requested and only one task is running per node, so with for instance `--nodes=N` or `--ntasks=N --ntasks-per-node=1` or a similar combination. It can be used to copy files from a network filesystem to a local filesystem.

If there is only one node and multiple tasks, the `srun` could cause problems by concurrently trying to write to the same file.

If there is only one task, then the `srun` are not really needed (except if you want to use `sstat` to monitor them).

In any case, consecutive `srun`'s are run on the same sets of nodes without cleaning.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to do this?

Comment: not without more specific information about the type of job and what the goal is